# HAML - how to style a few elements side by side?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, haml

I have these few lines in HAML:

```
.badge-container
  =badge_image(nil, @dis, :vertical)
  %h4= @dis.name
  %p= @dis.description
```

right now they line up one below the other, but I would like to have the image line up on the left and the name and discription to the right of the image.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the [1140 grid](http://cssgrid.net/) in my views. Using haml, I would achieve that with something like this:

```
.badge-container
  .row 
    .threecol
      =badge_image(nil, @dis, :vertical)
    .fivecol
        %h4= @dis.name
        %p= @dis.description
```

If you want to do this without a grid, you can visit the 1140 [github page](https://github.com/andytlr/cssgrid/tree/origin/css) to inspect the classes used in the code above.